# Temporary blank JPanel

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, thread-sleep

I'm having an issue with making a JPanel appear white when I want it to be blank. I'm creating a poker game, and because it all runs on one screen, I want to create a 5 second pause between actions so that people wouldn't see another player's hands.

I have a boolean that is active when it is a new players turn. I want it to paint the JPanel white, display a message asking them to wait, and after 5 seconds, it should repaint, showing the new player their cards.

When I run it though, it keeps the old information on screen while the 5 second pause takes place.

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent( g2 ); // call superclass's paintComponent
        this.setBackground( new Color(0, 153, 51) );
     if( this.newTurn ){
            g2.drawString("Starting next turn. . .", 400, 90);  //1000,300
            int[] pointsX = { 0, 1000, 1000, 0 };
            int[] pointsY = { 0, 0, 300, 300 };
            g2.fillPolygon( pointsX, pointsY, 4 );
            c1 = false;
            c2 = false;
            c3 = false;
            c4 = false;
            c5 = false;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            this.newTurn = false;
            repaint();
        }
```

What can I do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I think adding a panel on `GlassPane` with color white transperant color is all you need. Have a look at this question and also for pause use the Swing Timer or SwingWorker.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use Thread.sleep(), especially in the paintComponent() method.

This code will cause the GUI to sleep which means the GUI can't repaint itself.

If you want animation of some kind then you should be using a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). The Swing Timer code should NOT be in the paintComponent() method either. The Timer should be invoked where ever you invoke you "next players turn" logic.

Also, never invoke repaint() in a painting method. The painting code should just paint the current state of the component, it should not modify the properties or state of the component.

You can just display a "non decorated modal JDialog" with a JLabel containing the message you want to display. So you would start the Timer, then display the dialog and when the Timer fires you would hide the dialog.

Comment: But I edit the GUI before I sleep, so wouldn't it paint the new blank GUI, then sleep? Also, is using repaint() in the painting method really the big of a deal if I set the condition that causes the repaint to run to false?

Comment: @WillNasby The painting you do at `paintComponent()` does not go directly to the screen, but to some back buffer (remember swing is double buffered), so even though you do the drawing, it won't be visible since the EDT is blocked.

Comment: @WillNasby As for the `repaint()` - you do not get to micromanage drawing. The system may call `paintComponent()` for redraws or *partial* redraws at times when you do not expect it, and that can mess with your conditions. Just use a `Timer` like adviced, it's the correct way.